# Search a database for elements including a string variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm pretty new to SQLite and Python and have run into a bit of confusion. I'm trying to return all elements in a column that contain a substring which is passed to a function as a variable in Python. My code is running, but it's returning an empty result instead of the correct result.

Here's the code with the names generalized:

```
def myFunc(cursor,myString):
    return cursor.execute("""select myID from Column where name like '%'+?'%' """,(myString,))
```

Like I said, the code does run without error but returns an empty result instead of the result that I know it should be. I'm assuming it has something to do with my use of the wildcard and/or question mark, but I can't be sure. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for your time/help! Also, this is my first post, so I apologize in advance if I missed any of the recommended protocols for asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `'%'+?'%'` definitely isn't going to work—you're trying to concatenate with `+` on the left, but with no operator…

You can compute `LIKE`-search fields if you do it right—`'%'+?+'%'`, in this case. That will cause problems with some databases (from not working, to doing a less efficient search), but, at least according to CL.'s comment, sqlite3 will be fine.

But the easy thing to do is to just substitute a complete parameter, rather than part of one. You can put `%` into the parameters, and it'll be interpreted just fine. So:

```
return cursor.execute("""select myID from Column where name like ?""",
                      ('%'+myString+'%',))
```

And this also has the advantage that if you want to do a search for initial substrings (`'foo%'`), it'll be the same SQL statement but with a different parameter.

Comment: @CL.: Thanks. I didn't want to suggest that because I've had problems (many years ago, so this may no longer be true) doing that with other DB-API 2 databases. But if it works with sqlite3, the answer should say so. Edited.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
def myFunc(cursor,myString):
    return cursor.execute('select myID from Column where name like "{0}"'.format(myString))
```

Comment: This will [blow up](http://xkcd.com/327/) when the string contains double quotes.